# Building tree in Nim game

Tags: c, tree, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I want to create a game like Nim.

The player can take 1 or M (defined) cubes and the winner is the player who takes the last cube. I will also create a minimax function, so the MAX player (always plays first) is making the best move. I started writing my program but I have trouble creating the tree game. Here is my code:

```
#define M 30
#define K 4

char player[3] = "MAX";
int cubesCounter = M;

struct Node {
    int value;
    int numCubes;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

char switchPlayer() {
    if (strcmp(player, "MAX") == 0) {
        strcpy(player, "MIN");
    } else {
        strcpy(player, "MAX");
    }
}

struct Node buildGameTree() {
    struct Node *cube;
    cube->numCubes = M;

    cube->left = NULL;
    cube->right = NULL;

    if (cube->numCubes >= 1) {
        cube->numCubes = cube->numCubes - 1;
        cube->left = buildGameTree();
    }

    if (cube->numCubes >= M) {
        cube->numCubes = cube->numCubes - M;
        cube->right = buildGameTree();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error at these lines and I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
cube->left = buildGameTree();
cube->right = buildGameTree();
```

Can anyone help me with this function?

Comment: First of all your `buildGameTree` has to return something, I guess: the created/allocated node. Could you post the error?

Comment: There is no memory behind the `cube` pointer in `buildGameTree()`, so setting `numCubes` will cause undefined behaviour.  Plus you have unbounded recusion in the same function, because there is no termination condition.

Comment: IntelliSense: a value of type "struct Node" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct Node *"

Comment: I also added `if(cube->numCubes == 0){return cube;}` and a `return cube;` at the end of function but im getting the message tha i wrote in previous comment

Comment: "Im getting an error at these lines..." What error would that be? Perhaps the actual error message might be useful...

Comment: i wrote the error message in previous comment. Here it is :
 
IntelliSense: a value of type "struct Node" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct Node *"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `buildGameTree` should be:

```
struct Node *buildGameTree(){
    struct Node *cube= calloc(1,sizeof(struct Node));
    cube->numCubes = M;

    cube->left = NULL;
    cube->right = NULL;

    if (cube->numCubes >= 1){
        cube->numCubes = cube->numCubes - 1;
        cube->left = buildGameTree();
    }
    if (cube->numCubes >= M){
        cube->numCubes = cube->numCubes - M;
        cube->right = buildGameTree();
    }
    return (cube);
}
```

That is:

- allocate memory for the cube;
- return the allocated cube at end of function.

Some questions remain about what this function is to do, as it receives no parameters. Since `cube->numCubes` is always `M`, there will be an infinite recursion on `if (cube->numCubes >= 1)`.

Comment: i changed my function and now has an `int ncube` parameter so i call the `buildGameTree(ncubes - 1)` or `buildGameTree(ncubes - M)` . So now I think that the recursion will stop. I'll try this and i'll tell you if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and now is:

```
struct Node *buildGameTree(int ncubes){
    struct Node *cube = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node));
    cube->cubesRemaining = ncubes;

    if (cube->cubesRemaining >= 1){
        cube->left = buildGameTree(ncubes - 1);
        switchPlayer();
    }
    if (cube->cubesRemaining >= M){
        cube->right = buildGameTree(ncubes - M);
        switchPlayer();
    }

    return (cube);
}
```

Compiling the code i dont get an error problem. i'll test this when i'll finish my program.